# how to import UTC-JSON file through web3-eth methods

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, accounts, ethereum-classic, import

hey I am working on ethereum wallet. in this i want to import my account through UTC json file, but i didn't find any solution for this in web3-eth command someone can please help to find out the solution. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Better use [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/). It has built-in wallet import / export functionality in the standard UTC / JSON format.